# Accessing multiple calendars in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

We need the ability to access multiple google / Apple calendars from flutter. We are using the plugin "device_calendar: ^0.0.7". It works great but now the requirement is the ability to connect to multiple calendars. Is it possible to do this we will have the username password for these calendars, can these be passed dynamically from Flutter? Im struggling with how to do this properly.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried till now?

Comment: I haven’t tried anything yet I’m not sure how to do it or if it’s possible